# Web Content Highlights to be read at backend

Tags: java

I want to write a back end java program to listen to a text highlight event on the web browser and pass the highlighted text to my back end program. How can I do this?  Are there any libraries that support this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try Jodd - http://jodd.org/.  It has many utilities and some could be useful for your project.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to capture web browser events, you'll have to use JavaScript.

Using JavaScript, you could capture a text highlight event and then do an AJAX request to deliver the highlighted text to some sort of storage entity (for instance, a database or text file).

You could then have your Java back end program "listening" for updates to the database or text file and then do processing on the text.

So, at a high level...
1.  Capture text highlight (JavaScript)
2.  Perform AJAX request (JavaScript, Servlet)
3.  Read data (background Java process)